# Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 2.6.1 requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.0,3.8.0)' but it could not be found

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I want to create google app engine connected android project. I am trying to install Google Plugin for Eclipse 2.6.1, but it is showing this error.

Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 2.6.1.v201205091048-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 2.6.1.v201205091048-rel-r37) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.0,3.8.0)' but it could not be found

Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to install the 3.7 version of GPE on Eclipse Juno - that won't work. If you want to install GPE 2.6.1, the latest version of Eclipse that you can be on is Indigo (3.7).

GPE 3.2 will be coming out in a few weeks; it has an updated wizard for the App Engine Connected Android Project; the existing one is deprecated. If you can wait till then, you can install GPE 3.2 on Juno.

Comment: Rajeev, is there an update on when GPE 3.2 will be available?  Also, is it certain that the App Engine Connected Android Project will be restored within that release?  I only ask because someone posted back in July that this feature was removed in GPE v. 3.0.0 and that it was planned to be restored in the next version of GPE, but that hasn't happened as of 3.1.x (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-plugin-eclipse/_op9guM5pf4/BArAH-d3TgEJ)

Within a few days I'll need to decide whether to wait for it or to apply to test Endpoints or else to just hack together something using REST. TIA

Comment: I've just noticed elsewhere a Q&A with you that seems to indicate that GPE 3.2 will use Google Cloud Endpoints.  Does that mean that GPE 3.2 and the production release of Endpoints will be more or less synchronized?  Do testers for Endpoints have access to the App Engine Connected Android Project feature or something like it?  If so, that could make obtaining a tester account a good way for me to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with different Eclipse versions? Because when I search in google for "Google Plugin for Eclipse requires org.eclipse.platform.feature.group" I can see many people facing this issue.

Please check with some different versions of Eclipse.

Comment: I am using latest version of eclipse Juno. Should I try with older version?

Comment: Yes, if you don't have any specific Eclipse requirements.